# Normalising rows in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to normalize rows of a numpy matrix using L2 norm (unity length).

I am seeing a problem when I do that.

Assuming my matrix 'b' is as follows:

[image]

Now when I do the normalization of first row as below it works fine.

[image]

But when I try to do it by iterating through all the rows and converting the same matrix b as below it gives me all zeros.

Any idea why is that happening and how to get the correct normalization?.

Any faster way of row normalizing of matrix without having to iterate each row?. I don't want to use sci-kit learn normalization function though.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: try:- from __future__ import division

Comment: please put your code into code blocks. Do not use images - we cannot copy and run your code.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma: I don't think `from __future__ import division` will help in this case although it is good practice to do so if you are on Python2 (disregard altogether if you are on Python3). And note it is `__future__` and not `future`.

Comment: I added 2 underscores but somehow it became bold.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma: use the \` symbol to format as code. With: `__future__`, without: __future__.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the fact that `b` has type `int` so when you fill in row by row, `numpy` automatically converts the results of you computation (`float`) to `int`, hence the zeros. One way to avoid that is to define `b` with type `float` by using `0.`, `1.` etc... or just adding `.astype(float)` at definition.

This should work to do the computation in one go which also doesn't require converting to `float` first:

```
b = b / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

This works because you are redefining the whole array rather than changing its rows one by one, and `numpy` is clever enough to make it `float`.